# GAE, Python - module 'main' has no attribute application

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm following the second chapter in "Google App Engine With Python" and I've copied the code exactly like it is in the book, but I get a blank page when I try to open it now and it's giving me the following error:

```
ImportError: <module 'main' from '...../clock/main.pyc'> has no attribute application
```

I noticed it says main.pyc at the end there, it should be using main.py. Is this some kind of automatically generated file?

app.yaml

```
application: clock
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.9.6"
- name: markupsafe
  version: "0.15"
```

main.py

```
import datetime
import jinja2
import os
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import users

template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.getcwd()))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    user = users.get_current_user()
    login_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.path)
    logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.path)

    template = template_env.get_template('home.html')
    context = {
        'current_time': current_time,
        'user': user,
        'login_url': login_url,
        'logout_url': logout_url,
    }
    self.response.out.write(template.render(context))

    application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

`application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)`

should not be indented; as coded, it is part of the class `MainPage`'s `get` method, but it should be a module level variable, so not indented at all.